# Xbox 360 save backups and restoring

Tags: xbox-360

I am one to back up my saves(certain game saves don't allow copying). I am also one to format a HDD without realising certain saves were not backed up. Point is, I began backing up my USB Xbox360 save files to my computer for later restoration if this were to happen again.
Now realising I have misplaced an important save, and that the saves are somewhere backed up on a HDD or my P.C. I have found some and tried to copy them back to a USB. I realise that it must be the same USB stick size and type.
It is not working.
So, I am looking for a legitimate way to view my saves or restore them without using a modifying program or hack or whatever.
I recall I had an Exploder(cheat save thing) but don't know what I've done with it as I never used it. 
Can I use Xploder(the program) or another program to do this?
I know it is possible, and want it to be legitimate(my saves, not modified).
Help?

Comment: So I recovered the saves though, was only because I used the correct USB from prior.